# How to use ray parallelism within a class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, parallel-processing, ray

I want to use the ray *task* method rather than the ray *actor* method to parallelise a method within a class. The reason being the latter seems to need to change how a class is instantiated (as shown [here](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/#getting-started-with-ray)). A toy code example is below, as well as the error

```
import numpy as np
import ray


class MyClass(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        ray.init(num_cpus=4)
    
    @ray.remote
    def func(self, x, y):
        return x * y
    
    def my_func(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        b = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
        result = []
        # we wish to parallelise over the array `a`
        for sub_array in np.array_split(a, 3):
            result.append(self.func.remote(sub_array, b))
        return result

mc = MyClass()
mc.my_func()
>>> TypeError: missing a required argument: 'y'
```

The error arises because ray does not seem to be "aware" of the class, and so it expects an argument `self`.

The code works fine if we do not use classes:

````
@ray.remote
def func(x, y):
    return x * y

def my_func():
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    b = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
    result = []
    # we wish to parallelise over the list `a`
    # split `a` and send each chunk to a different processor
    for sub_array in np.array_split(a, 4):
        result.append(func.remote(sub_array, b))
    return result


res = my_func()
ray.get(res)
>>> [array([-0.41929678, -0.83227786, -2.69814232, ..., -0.67379119,
        -0.79057845, -0.06862196]),
 array([-0.83859356, -1.66455572, -5.39628463, ..., -1.34758239,
        -1.5811569 , -0.13724391]),
 array([-1.25789034, -2.49683358, -8.09442695, ..., -2.02137358,
        -2.37173535, -0.20586587]),
 array([ -1.67718712,  -3.32911144, -10.79256927, ...,  -2.69516478,
         -3.1623138 ,  -0.27448782])]```
````

We see the output is a list of 4 arrays, as expected. How can I get `MyClass` to work with parallelism using ray?

Answer (score 4):

a few tips:

1. It's generally recommended that you only use the `ray.remote` decorator on functions or classes in python (not bound methods).
2. You should be very very careful about calling `ray.init` inside the constructor of a function, since `ray.init` is **not** idempotent (which means your program will fail if you instantiate multiple instances of `MyClass`). Instead, you should make sure `ray.init` is only run once in your program.

I think there's 2 ways of achieving the results you're going for with Ray here.

You could move `func` out of the class, so it becomes a function instead of a bound method. Note that in this approach `MyClass` will be serialized, which means that changes that `func` makes to `MyClass` will not be reflected anywhere outside the function. In your simplified example, this doesn't appear to be a problem. This approach makes it easiest to achieve the most parallelism.

```
@ray.remote
def func(obj, x, y):
    return x * y


class MyClass(object):
    def my_func(self):
        ...
        # we wish to parallelise over the array `a`
        for sub_array in np.array_split(a, 3):
            result.append(func.remote(self, sub_array, b))
        return result
```

The other approach you could consider is to use [async actors](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/async_api.html). In this approach, the ray actor will handle concurrency via asyncio, but this [comes with the limitations of asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code).

```
@ray.remote(num_cpus=4)
class MyClass(object):
    async def func(self, x, y):
        return x * y
    
    def my_func(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        b = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
        result = []
        # we wish to parallelise over the array `a`
        for sub_array in np.array_split(a, 3):
            result.append(self.func.remote(sub_array, b))
        return result
```

Comment: it does not work with complex functions, since it gives serialization error. ray does not know how to serialize your function.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code:

```
@ray.remote
class Prime:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self,number) :
       self.num = number

    def SumPrime(self,num) :
       tot = 0
       for i in range(3,num):
           c = 0
           for j in range(2, int(i**0.5)+1):
                if i%j == 0:
                    c = c + 1
           if c == 0:
              tot = tot + i
      return tot
            
num = 1000000    
start = time.time()
# make an object of Check class
prime = Prime.remote(num)


print("duration =", time.time() - start, "\nsum_prime = ", ray.get(prime.SumPrime.remote(num)))
```

Comment: You must show the way to parallelize for at least two functions in a class.