# ray tune in class function

Tags: python, ray

I want to run a class function by the Ray Tune library like below.

But it returns error('TypeError: missing a required argument: 'param').

Is there any other way to run this successfully?

```
import ray as ray

class A:

    @ray.remote
    def test(self, param):
        print(param)
        return {'r':1}


    def run(self):
        datas = [self.test.remote(param) for param in range(10)]
        # for i in range(10):
        #     self.test.remote(i)


ray.init()
a = A()
a.run()

# rs = []
# while len(datas):
#     done, datas = ray.wait(datas)
#     r = ray.get(done[0])
#     rs.append(r)
# print(rs)
```

Below is the stacktrace.

```
    datas = [self.test.remote(param) for param in range(10)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ray/remote_function.py", line 111, in _remote_proxy
    return self._remote(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **self._default_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 303, in _invocation_remote_span
    return method(self, args, kwargs, *_args, **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ray/remote_function.py", line 319, in _remote
    return invocation(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ray/remote_function.py", line 287, in invocation
    list_args = ray._private.signature.flatten_args(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ray/_private/signature.py", line 114, in flatten_args
    raise TypeError(str(exc)) from None
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'param'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get

Comment: I added the traces.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/64321153/4046632

Comment: Also https://towardsdatascience.com/modern-parallel-and-distributed-python-a-quick-tutorial-on-ray-99f8d70369b8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.remote()` has more parameters....

Try to explicitly define it:

```
self.test.remote(param)
# change to
self.test.remote(param=param)
```